# implementing SAML single sign on in odoo to the application in Microsoft azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, odoo, saml-2.0

i'm trying implement single sign on for Azure AD application to the odoo. i have created application and added SSO settings in Azure, i have downloaded auth_saml and installed in odoo. Then i have configured odoo saml providers. when i'm testing connection from azure i'm getting500 error and likewise from the oddo. i'm pasting the error log at the bottom, please help and i'm stuck here for 2 days. thank you in advance.

```
 2021-12-10 02:57:32,491 29639 ERROR mydb werkzeug: Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hemanthbethu/Xaana/enigma/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 237, in _dispatch
    result = request.dispatch()
  File "/Users/hemanthbethu/Xaana/enigma/odoo/http.py", line 810, in dispatch
    r = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/Users/hemanthbethu/Xaana/enigma/odoo/http.py", line 359, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/hemanthbethu/Xaana/enigma/odoo/service/model.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/hemanthbethu/Xaana/enigma/odoo/http.py", line 348, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/Users/hemanthbethu/Xaana/enigma/odoo/http.py", line 916, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/Users/hemanthbethu/Xaana/enigma/odoo/http.py", line 535, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/Users/hemanthbethu/Xaana/enigma/addons/auth_saml/controllers/main.py", line 137, in get_auth_request
    self._get_saml_extra_relaystate(), request.httprequest.url_root.rstrip("/")
  File "/Users/hemanthbethu/Xaana/enigma/addons/auth_saml/models/auth_saml_provider.py", line 216, in _get_auth_request
    saml_client = self._get_client_for_provider(url_root)
  File "/Users/hemanthbethu/Xaana/enigma/addons/auth_saml/models/auth_saml_provider.py", line 194, in _get_client_for_provider
    spConfig = self._get_config_for_provider(base_url)
  File "/Users/hemanthbethu/Xaana/enigma/addons/auth_saml/models/auth_saml_provider.py", line 186, in _get_config_for_provider
    "key_file": self._get_cert_key_path("sp_pem_private"),
  File "/Users/hemanthbethu/Xaana/enigma/addons/auth_saml/models/auth_saml_provider.py", line 146, in _get_cert_key_path
    keys_path = model_attachment._full_path(keys.store_fname)
  File "/Users/hemanthbethu/Xaana/enigma/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_attachment.py", line 91, in _full_path
    path = re.sub('[.]', '', path)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 194, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
Exception

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 306, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 294, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/hemanthbethu/Xaana/enigma/odoo/service/server.py", line 476, in app
    return self.app(e, s)
  File "/Users/hemanthbethu/Xaana/enigma/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 112, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/hemanthbethu/Xaana/enigma/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 87, in application_unproxied
    result = odoo.http.root(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/hemanthbethu/Xaana/enigma/odoo/http.py", line 1313, in __call__
    return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/hemanthbethu/Xaana/enigma/odoo/http.py", line 1279, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/middleware/shared_data.py", line 220, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/hemanthbethu/Xaana/enigma/odoo/http.py", line 1489, in dispatch
    result = ir_http._dispatch()
  File "/Users/hemanthbethu/Xaana/enigma/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 241, in _dispatch
    return cls._handle_exception(e)
  File "/Users/hemanthbethu/Xaana/enigma/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 209, in _handle_exception
    return request._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/Users/hemanthbethu/Xaana/enigma/odoo/http.py", line 748, in _handle_exception
    return super(HttpRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/Users/hemanthbethu/Xaana/enigma/odoo/http.py", line 301, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object - - -
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the path to the cert or the key is not set. So the module attempts to process an empty string and fails.

This might be happening although you did not check the "Sign" checkbox, which is bug in version 3.0, reported here:  https://github.com/OCA/server-auth/issues/315. as a temporary workaround create a cert and key and upload them, keep the sign button unchecked.

If you decide to use the "Sign" checkbox, you might run into further issues such as described in https://github.com/OCA/server-auth/issues/321 where an error is raised in case the identity provider did not sign the assertion.